# Can't resolve objects using EL

Tags: java, jsp, el

```
public class Foo extends Properties {
    public String getVal(){
         return "2";
    }
}
```

In my HttpServlet class' doGet(..) method I am doing this,

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
request.setAttribute("key", foo);
```

Then in the .jsp is this code,

```
1  ${key}
2  ${key.val}
3  <%=request.getAttribute("key")%>
4  <%=((Foo)request.getAttribute("key")).getVal()%>
```

And this is the output,

```
1  {}
2  
3  {}
4  2
```

Could anyone tell my why ${key.val} doesn't work?

[Edit] I am only interested on the one property from the foo class, since it seems there is no way to access the getVar() call using EL(Right?), would a viable alternative be to jsut put?

```
request.setAttribute("key_val", foo.getVal());
```

Foo is a sub class of a subclass of the Properties class so there is no way for me to decouple them easily.

Comment: Are you sure you are providing the real code? Because <$= would not work.

Comment: oops, sorry about that, it should be a %

Comment: @Andrew: Can you add some additional text your sample code and output so we can clearly see what output gets generated by what code? Also make sure you show us raw output (i.e. from view-source), not mangled by browser.

Comment: Does your Foo class implement java.util.Map? If so, ${key.val} may call Foo.get("val") instead of Foo.getVal().

Comment: It extends java.util.Properties, however the getVal() method was implemented by me.

Comment: @andrew: java.util.Properties extends Hashtable which implements a Map! Try setting foo.put("val", "some string"), and you should see "some string" in your output.

Comment: Touché. Does that mean I have to do something different?

Comment: Something different here means not extending Properties, otherwise all ${key.anything} will always use foo.get("anything") :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Foo` class has a `toString()` method which prints like `{}` and the `val` probably called the wrong getter. Add some debug lines/breakpoints to the getter calls. If in vain, post more detail of how the `Foo` class look like.

Comment: This would indeed explain the behaviour.

Comment: If Foo implements Map, ${key.val} could be translated to Foo.get("val") too. Alternatively, JavaBeans info may define different method for "val" property, although I've never seen that in practice.

Comment: I overrode the toString() method and added a break point to the getter, The toString() method is indeed what produces the "{}", however the getVal method is only called for the call on line 4.

Comment: Is it a `public` method? Really, we need more detail about the `Foo` class.

Comment: It extends Properties, but the getVal() method was implemented by me, it is public, and it is able to return the right value, you can see that in line 4 of my example.

Comment: `Properties` in turn implements `Map`. Its `get()` method is preferred over this in EL. That's why you're seeing this behaviour. I'd suggest to have `Foo` compose instead of inherit it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have EL disabled? Check these two answers for possible reasons and solutions:

- [EL in a JSP stopped evaluating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504071/el-in-a-jsp-stopped-evaluating/504186#504186)
- [Javascript String.replace(/\$/,str) works weirdly in jsp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472500/javascript-string-replace-str-works-weirdly-in-jsp-file/472573#472573)

Another possibility is that you have `key` bound to something different in your other contexts. This code:

```
${key}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
<%= page.findAttribute("key") %>
```

and not `<%= request.getAttribute("key") %>`. It searches for in pageContext first, then request, session and application context at last.

Comment: What would be the correct syntax for getting foo from the request object then?

Comment: If you only want to use object from request scope, you need to use `${request.key}` or `${request['key']}`. But typically, `${key}` is what you want. I just wrote that answer as a possibility.

Comment: Both ${request.key} and ${request['key']} return nothing when I use them. When you say ${key} is what I want, do you mean that my syntax should be correct?

Comment: @Andrew: yes, your syntax looks OK. I'm sorry, it should have been ${requestScope.key} or ${requestScope["key"]}.