# use checkbox Display Tag in Struts

Tags: struts, displaytag

A list is passed to the display:table. In the table i need to have a checkbox column to select/deselect any transactions that are selected. How do i associate the checked item with the transaction. Also i need to pass this checked transaction to a java script.
Thanks

Jsp code:

```
<display:column title="<input type='checkbox' name='selectall' onClick='selectAll()' />" media="html">
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectBox" class="selectableCheckbox" id="selectBox" value="${sample.txniD}"></>
</display:column>
<display:column property="txniD" sortable="true" scope="all" title="Transaction ID %>" />
```

Comment: You already associated it, since the value of the checkbox is the corresponding transaction ID. WHat's the problem exactly?

Comment: Thanks JB.to verify in the onClick='selectAll' js i added an alert to print the value selected.  selectAll() { 
 
 var selectall = document.getElementsByName("selectall");
 var checkboxArray = document.getElementsByName('selectBox');
 if(selectall[0].checked == true){
  for(var i = 0 ; i<checkboxArray.length; i++){
      checkboxArray[i].checked=true;
      alert(checkboxArray[i].toString);
     }
 }else{
  for(var i = 0 ; i<checkboxArray.length; i++){
      
      checkboxArray[i].checked=false;
      
     } 
 }
}
the alert returns "object" .I was expecting it to print the Transaction ID

Comment: selectAll() {  var selectall = document.getElementsByName("selectall"); var checkboxArray = document.getElementsByName('selectBox'); if(selectall[0].checked == true){ for(var i = 0 ; i<checkboxArray.length; i++){ checkboxArray[i].checked=true; alert(checkboxArray[i].toString); } }else{ for(var i = 0 ; i<checkboxArray.length; i++){ checkboxArray[i].checked=false; } } }

Answer (score 0):

Try alerting the `value` of the checkbox, `alert(checkboxArray[i].value);`, not `toString`.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for answering. But "${sample.txniD}", does not work. Instead of printing the Txn id. It prints "${sample.txniD}". Any suggestions as to how i can fetch the txn id?

Comment: Looks like that EL expression is not evaluated. Are you using EL in other places on the same page and are they working?

Comment: No i am not using EL expressions anywhere else.

Comment: IMO, I think first, you have to make sure that EL is not ignored in your jsp. You might want to refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/793983/738746