# Assigning Java variable value to Javascript variable

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

How to assign a java variable vale to an javascript varible. I have tried the following scripting elements:

```
<%
double x=23.35;
%>
var temp='<%= x %>';
var temp="<%= x %>";
var temp='${x}';
```

they returned an output as follows:

```
<%= x %>
<%= x %>
${x}
```

Comment: You might want to try this - [JSP: EL expression is not evaluated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/793983/738746).

Comment: I tried your suggestion Bhesh but no change in my output. Actually I am not working on an web application, but calling this jsp file from a java code. I am working on SWT browser for uploading google maps

Comment: Is this in a JSP or in a JS file? Also, have you considered making an AJAX call and returning JSON?

Comment: It's probably because your java call is in quotations. Try `var temp = <%= x %>`. If this is a JSP file, the value should be replaced before the JavaScript interpreter gets to it.

Comment: var temp = <%= x %> would not load my google map. it seems that it is not accepting value through that scripting style

Comment: @ShashankBhagat: 'I am working on SWT browser' - does this mean your application is a desktop application, rather than a web application?  In that case, why are you using JSPs?

Answer (score 1):

Try this-it should work. (No '=' needed inside java code).

```
var temp=<% x %>;
var temp=<% x %>;
var temp=${x};
```

Comment: without the '=' sign it gives an error. And ${x} does not load my google map means it is not accepting that value.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried three ways. I have tried in JSP inside the script tag and below work for me fine except for the third way.

```
 <% double x = 23.35; %>
    
 var temp = <%=x%>;
 console.log(temp);
 console.log(typeof(temp));

 var temp2 = '<%=x%>';
 console.log(temp2);
 console.log(typeof(temp2));

 var temp3 = "<%=x%>";
 console.log(temp3);
 console.log(typeof(temp3));
```

The difference is if we assign value to a variable within single quotes or double quotes, it treated as a string otherwise number. If you assign value as `<c:set name="x" value="23.35" />` then can access by `'${x}'`.